# PyCharm interpreter referencing

Tags: python, pycharm

I have un-installed all the previous python versions and installed a new Python 3.8.0. After following the installation tutorial for the changing interpreter for PyCharm, I found that PyCharm is taking the correct path for system interpreter python.exe but has the wrong reference i.e. Python 3.7 (1) as shown in below pic, I was wondering what effect it will make.

[image: m]

Comment: What is PyCharm version?

Comment: Better switch to 3.8.3. Not sure which 3.8.0 build you have, but if it is some alpha or beta I wont be surprised to see PyCharm failing to detect the proper interpreter version.

Comment: @user2235698 PyCharm 2018.2.3 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-182.4323.49, built on September 4, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 2018.2 does not have any knowledge about Python 3.8 (since it was released in 2019) and hence marks your interpreter as Python 3.7 (the freshest supported version). It is enough to update PyCharm.